# How to build OpenCV with Java under Linux using command line?(Gonna use it in MapReduce)

Tags: java, linux, opencv, build, mapreduce

Recently I'm trying OpenCV out for my graduation project.
I've had some success under Windows enviroment. And because with Windows package of OpenCV it comes with pre-built libraries, so I don't have to worry about how to build them.
But since the project is suppose to run on a cluster with CentOS as host OS for each node, I have to know how to correctly compile, and run these library under Linux enviroment.

I've set up a VM with VirtualBox and installed Ubuntu 13.04 on it.
But so far I still can't find a way to adjust the settings of CMakeList to make Java a build target. (A jar, and a native library so I can import and use them in MapReduce program)
Following is the official tutorial of desktop Java for OpenCV

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

The part about the compiling is pretty brief. So I still can't quite understand it.
Is it because I missed some dependency for Java? I've already got JVM(Jre-7u7) installed.
Or is it because I didn't configure CMakeList.txt correctly?

Here is the things I've done so far, other than that it's a complete clean Ubuntu

1. Installed vim
2. Installed g++
3. Installed cmake
4. installed cmake-curses-gui
5. installed java7 JVM
6. download OpenCV package for Linux

The target enviroment is Cluster with CentOS as host OS for each node, and the project is a MapReduce program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?   Have you looked at the instructions here too? http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html  (given how big the build process is, don't post the entire output - just the last few lines before the error).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Probably what you're missing is `ant`, which is a java oriented build tool.

When you go:

```
cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ../opencv-2.4.5/
```

(i.e. where you're configuring the make for your machine), check for the section that says **java**.  It should say something like this (possibly with different paths/versions):

```
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.8.2)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include
--     Java tests:                  YES
```

When I first ran cmake, I had this:

```
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java tests:                  YES
```

Which indicated it couldn't find `ant`, and so it didn't create a .jar file.
I simply use the version that's in the repository:

```
sudo apt-get install ant
```

I ran cmake again, with the above options, which got the path to ant (and I got JNI for free!).

**Note:** You probably want to read the output of cmake fairly carefully as it tells you what it's going to build on your machine, and you may have some missing libraries.

**If you find JNI is still missing.**

cmake is (mostly? first? conveniently? can be interpreted as?) looking for jni.h, which should be specifically `$JAVA_HOME/include/jni.h`  So you need to set $JAVA_HOME to the home folder of your jdk.

I used `which javac` and then `ls -l` to follow a series of symbolic links, to identify where my java 1.7 install was.  You could also use `locate jni.h` and work up the tree, or simply look around `/usr/lib/jvm` or similar.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

You probably want to check that you've got that right with a couple of

```
ls $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac

ls $JAVA_HOME/include/jni.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h
```

Interestingly when I ran the cmake command again, it picked up a different JNI folder:

```
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include
```

Once you've got that, run the `make` command.  If you watch obsessively, you'll see a bunch of .java files trundle past.  Either way you'll end up with a .jar file in the ./bin folder.
(in my case it's called `opencv-245.jar` as that's the version of the code I downloaded).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I've installed Ant, and it's been correctly detected by Cmake, but somehow JNI is still "not found". If I want to manually set the path, what directory should I point it to? The directory of JVM?

Comment: Have added some notes to my answer about where cmake is looking for JNI - good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
I've got it working on my VM, thanks for the hep!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried manually installing ant but didn't help. Following your post, I installed ant trough the package manager on OSX homebrew by saying `brew install ant`, restarting the terminal and trying again. This worked for me. THANKKS

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you! My problem was the ANT. To solve the JNI not found problem, you have to export JAVA_HOME="your java path directory" as explained by this answer. Mine was at "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"

Answer (score 1):

For someone directed here from google :

If your JRE crashes after you run the java tutorials then most probably you have the python Bindings installed as well (cv2.so) . You will have to re-make OpenCV without those bindings

`cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=NO`

That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build OpenCV 3 on Ubuntu 14 and encountered similar problems with Oracle java 8 JDK.

These are the steps I preformed to build and run a java program using the java OpenCV bindings.

1. **FindJNI.** Since the "FindJNI" module of cmake 3 doesn't support the detection of Oracle Java 8, we have to add our Java 8 directories manually. Therefore, locate the file `FindJNI.cmake` in your cmake directory,e.g `/home/foo/bar/cmake-3.2.2-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindJNI.cmake`

   Goto the `JAVA_APPEND_LIBRARY_DIRECTORIES` variable and add the path to your java lib architecture directory, e.g. `/home/foo/bar/jdk1.8.0_45/lib/amd64`

   Goto the `JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` variable and add the path to your java include directory, e.g. `/home/foo/bar/jdk1.8.0_45/include`
2. **Build.** The shared lib flag tiggers the build of the java bindings, 
   if your modified FindJNI found your Oracle 8 JDK.

   > ```
   > cd /home/foo/bar/opencv-3.0.0/
   > mkdir build
   > cd build
   > # install dependencies if needed, see [1]
   > cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
   > make -j
   > ```
3. **Write Testcode.** In your `build` directory you should see a jar file like `./bin/opencv-300.jar`. This file can be added to your java build dependencies, e.g. in your favorite IDE.
4. **Run Testcode.** You have to add the opencv lib path to your VM options:

   > -Djava.library.path=/home/foo/bar/opencv-3.0.0/build/lib

[1] Note: Depending on your personal needs or taste you can install various other dependencies before building, e.g. compare http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Remark: For OpenCV 3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 with cmake 3.5.1, the first step is not needed anymore. The corresponding other steps are still valid though.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.1.0 of OpenCV there is a Maven POM project under `OpenCV_Root_Directory/platforms/maven`. With Maven installed on your Linux machine (using package manager or manually installed) this project will ensure you have the correct dependencies installed, build the native and Java libraries. See the README in the above directory.

Answer (score 0):

--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).