# Building Java package for OpenCV in linux

Tags: java, opencv

When I do the cmake command the "To be build" section doesn't appear java, what could be the reason for that? I've java installed in my machinewhic

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib-master/modules/ ..

To be built:
core flann imgproc ml photo reg surface_matching video dnn fuzzy
imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect plot superres ts xobjdetect
xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency
text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo structured_light tracking
videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow stitching python2
```

Java version

```
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

The environment variable is also rightfully set:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

references: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Can it find Apache Ant? It seems to be required as well. Just edit the `# --- Java Support ---` section of the top-level CMakeLists.txt and add a couple of messages to see if the dependency detection finds what's required.

Comment: yes it does. Thank you the quick reply. I forgot to add this reference as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386551/how-to-build-opencv-with-java-under-linux-using-command-linegonna-use-it-in-ma

Comment: Now that I understood your comment, apparently it could not find JNI I'll have to take a look of that tomorrow. I'll post it then

Comment: Hmm, the `JAVA_HOME` variable, where does it point? Seems like the java binary to me. What if you shorten it to only `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/` ? Looking at the CMake module `FindJNI.cmake`, that seems to be the issue.

Comment: Thank you Dan you were right. I edited the FindJNI.cmake and added the right path to the JDK and JRE libraries, after that I also needed to change the environment path to not to point to their binaries but to point to JDK and JRE directories so I was able to run ant.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to write up your solution as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Extract JDK to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_77/` set environment variables in `/etc/environment` and in `~/.profile`.

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_77/"
JRE_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_77/jre/"
```

add java and javac to /usr/bin

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java" 1000
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/javac" 1000
```

make it sure that they are currently selected:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

In the file `/usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindJNI.cmake` in the section `JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY_DIRECTORIES` include

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_77/jre/lib/{libarch}
```

and in the section `JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` include

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_77/include
```

Install 'ant' and check if `/usr/bin/ant -version` doesn't say that JAVA_HOME is in the wrong path or something.
Finally cmake now should be able to compile libraries for java as well.

Thank you Dan.

*addendum*:

To compile OpenCv's extra module in java go to CMakeList.txt contained in the directory of the preferred module and add 'java' to the line:

```
ocv_define_module(face opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_objdetect WRAP python java)
```

Unset BUILD_SHARED_LIBS, BUILD_EXAMPLES, BUILD_TESTS, BUILD_PERF_TESTS, flags and set OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH to path: `opencv_contrib/modules/`.